# How can I make my fetch requests include "Last-Modified" headers automatically?

Tags: http-headers, browser-cache, fetch-api, last-modified

I'm using fetch api (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

I'm getting a response with "Last-Modified" header (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified)

When I run the fetch a second time, it does not include the "Last-Modified" header in the request, and therefor fails at caching.

---

I have read the following on caching and fetch (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache) but it works with ETags.

---

**How can I make fetch include the "Last-Modified" header?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Last-Modified` is a *response* header, not a *request* header.

The corresponding request header is [`If-Modified-Since`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-Modified-Since). That's what you should expect to see in the request if you want caching.

Comment: Strange.  I was seeing both, or neither.  I've since switched over to ETags.